# comparing datetime less than or equal to not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime, nhibernate

I have a query that gets data from the database. The user can select a date range for getting the data. I want my date range filters to be inclusive, so if a user selects date from and date to, the query should do the following:

```
all dates >= date FROM
AND
all dates <= date TO
```

this is working fine for the date FROM, I'm getting everything greater AND equal to the date FROM. But for date TO, its not including the date, just getting everything LESS than the date TO.

here's the code:

```
query = query
   .Where(x => x.TradeDt >= tradeDFrom)
   .Where(x => x.TradeDt <= tradeDTo);
```

Comment: Are your dates DateTime or String?  Is tradeDTo null or real values?

Comment: @jdweng its `DateTime` thats why the question has that as a tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TradeDt is likely a datetime, and the time portion isn't midnight, while your tradeDTo's time portion is midnight.  Add a day to tradeDTo, and use <

```
tradeDTo=tradeDTo.AddDays(1);
query = query
   .Where(x => x.TradeDt >= tradeDFrom)
   .Where(x => x.TradeDt < tradeDTo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to compare only the date part.

```
query = query
  .Where(x => x.TradeDt.Date >= tradeDFrom.Date)
  .Where(x => x.TradeDt.Date <= tradeDTo.Date);
```